# Sending Emails With Swift Mailer on Google Cloud using the Mailgun Service Provider

Tags: symfony, smtp, google-cloud-platform, mailgun

I have a Symfony 3.4 app and FOSUserBundle installed with it. I deployed the app to Compute Engine instance. However, when I try to send emails after each registration, I get the following error.

```
 Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be 
 established
 with host smtp.mailgun.org [Connection timed out #110] [] []
```

Here is my parameters.yml file

```
parameters:
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: smtp.mailgun.org
    mailer_user: postmaster@mydomain.tdl
    mailer_password: mailerpass
```

I also tried

```
mailer_host: smtp.mailgun.org:587
```

I added the 587 outgoing port to the firewall rules list on the Google Cloud platform, but that did not help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like on Compute Engine you should use port `2525` because outbound connections on ports 25, 465, and 587 is not allowed. You can read more on Mailgun [documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#sending-via-smtp) and Google Cloud Platform [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/) and [more](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-mailgun).

Answer (score 1):

Google Compute Engine has all standard outgoing SMTP ports blocked by design. Please vote here to get Google's SMTP behavior changed:
https://googlecloudplatform.uservoice.com/forums/302595-compute-engine/suggestions/10079937-send-and-receive-email-using-tcp-smtp-imap-ports

Until they open the SMTP ports, there will be no good way to send email from their cloud servers. Sendgrid and the others are too expensive and lack many features that are needed.